# How can I tell if the power pin(?) inside my laptop has been pushed in?

Tags: adapter

My laptop (a Packard Bell EasyNote S4) recently stopped charging properly.

The connector suddenly felt very loose in the back and I thought part of that had come out and gone missing. Unfortunately despite searching thoroughly I was never able to find anything. I bought what I thought was a compatible adapter and charger from eBay but it didn't fit. I tried again with the original adapter but it seemed even worse than before - in fact it felt like the connector wasn't holding the internal pin at all.

Is it possible that this part (I think it's called the jack?) has been pushed in? If so, what can I do? If not, any other ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: it sounds possible, could you possibly upload a picture?

Comment: I'll go so far as to say it sounds *likely*, but a picture would help immensely.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that this part (I think it's called the jack?) has been pushed in?

It is certainly possible. A visual inspection should answer the question. Gentle probing should prove whether the visible pins are loose.

> If so, what can I do?

- send it for repair.
- disassemble the laptop and attempt to

  - repair the connector, or
  - replace the connector
  - solder a short cable to an external connector

> If not, any other ideas of what could be going wrong?

- The battery might be faulty.
- The power adapter might be faulty.
- A fuse may have blown.
- A power surge may have damaged electronic components in the laptop.
- The on-off switch may be broken.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, me and the bf took it apart and indeed it was pushed back, the piece of plastic that had kept it in place had snapped. We managed to wedge it in place and it all seems to be working fine. Never been so happy to be dating a geek lol.     GEEKS RULE!!